# Excel List Sheet Names + Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I have an Excel Workbook with Several sheets. Whithin each sheet I have 2 cell values with dates (Begin Date and End Date).

My Goal is to create a new Sheet (Index Sheet) that has a table that lists all existing sheets in the workbook, and, for each Sheet I would have the correspondent cell values for Begin Date and End Date.

Something like this:

Name          Begin Date     End Date

Sheet01       01/01/2016     01/02/2016

Sheet02       12/02/2016     23/03/2016

Sheet03       22/03/2016     30/04/2016

Sheet04       22/12/2016     01/12/2016

How can I do this (If possible avoid VBA, I`m not a developer :))

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Where are these values located within the sheets?

Comment: While there are a few methods to get the list of sheets, it is faster and easier to hand type them.  Once the the list is created it is just a matter of using the INDIRECT() function.  `INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!D1")` where A1 is the cell in which the first sheet name is and D1 is the cell on the respective sheet with the date desired.  Then it can be dragged down.

Comment: The value for Begin Date is in D5 and for End Date is in F5, these values are consistent accross all Sheets

Comment: Then if your list starts in A1 then your two formulas would be `=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!D5")` and `=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!F5")` then drag these formulas down to the end of the list of sheets.

Comment: That Worked OK (=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!D5") and =INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!F5")) - Now was thinking how to create a link that moves the user to the correct sheet, do you know how can I do this using this table?

Comment: look into hyperlinks. See [HERE](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/49296/microsoft-excel-create-a-hyperlink-to-another-worksheet-or-excel-sheet/)

Comment: Thank you. I know How to create links, But I wanted to automatically generate links base on the name of the sheet

Answer (score 1):

You could just put a reference, like "=Sheet1!B2"  where B2 would be the cell in Sheet 1 that has the date you want.

Answer (score 1):

If the dates are in cells **A1** and **B1** of each sheet, then:

```
Sub IndexMaker()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, n As String

    With ThisWorkbook
            .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "index"
            Set sh = ActiveSheet
    End With

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        n = Sheets(i).Name
        v1 = Sheets(i).Range("A1").Value
        v2 = Sheets(i).Range("B1").Value
        If n <> "index" Then
            sh.Cells(i, "A").Value = n
            sh.Cells(i, "B").Value = v1
            sh.Cells(i, "C").Value = v2
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You mean `n As String` and NOT `sn As String`...?

Answer (score 0):

use below code . and i am assuming that u have begin date and end date at cell b2 and c2 respectively of every sheet.

```
Sub SheetNames()
Columns(1).Insert
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(i).Name
Cells(i, 2) = Sheets(i)!B2
Cells(i, 3) = Sheets(i)!C2
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do I place this code and How do I use it insi the Table?

Comment: Hi,
Sorry for the late reply . you do not need to place this table .instead you need to save this code in macro /vba part of excel.